# Using 'find' with selectors and filter ':not' with some selectors

Tags: jquery, filter, find

Does anyone know this? or can tell where I'm missing?

this instruction works (only one selector in `:not` filter)

ie:

```
$('#menuStato > li > a').find('+ ul > li:not(.toggleMenuActions)')
```

when I use the :not filter with two or more class selector inside separated by `','` on a selector that start with `'+'` in a find function

the result is an empty array

ie:

```
$('#menuStato > li > a').find('+ ul > li:not(.toggleMenuActions, .toggleMenuFooter, .nascosto)')
```

The same instruction written like the follow works... (I just moved the `' > a '` from the fist brackets to the second one

ie:

```
$('#menuStato > li').find(' > a + ul > li:not(.toggleMenuActions, .toggleMenuFooter, .nascosto)')
```

Comment: Note that `:not(.foo, .bar)` is jQuery-only and isn't (yet?) valid CSS, for which you would use `:not(.foo):not(.bar)`.

Comment: yes it's jQuery-only.
I made a jsFiddle to test it:  http://jsfiddle.net/XHjqL/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` should retrieve *descendents* elements, while in your first selector

```
$('#menuStato > li > a').find('+ ul..)
```

you're looking for a *sibling* element (that's the reason why instead your last statement

```
$('#menuStato > li').find(' > a...)
```

properly works)

regards, Fabrizio.